# Visual Studio 2022 Community Unable to Run after uninstalling VS2022 Community Preview

Tags: visual-studio, gac, visual-studio-2022

Afternoon all,

I had been using the Visual Studio 2022 Preview.  Recently I decided to switch to the Release version.  I uninstalled VS2022 Preview and installed the 2022 Community Release.

The install runs fine and completes with no issues.  However when trying to run VS2022 It comes up with the error attached below.

From my talks with MS found at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-launch-VS-Comunity-2022-after/1596301?entry=myfeedback&viewtype=all It appears VS2022 Community should be running version 17.0 of the .Threading DLL.  However no matter what I have tried it refuses to load.

I have run the uninstaller with -F. Re-installed several times.
Attempted to install  17.0 to the GAC but this does not change the outcome
As per the post on the developer community pretty much everything short of re-installing windows (Which I am 100% trying to avoid)

I ran the FusionLog viewer (Attached) and it looks like there is something re-binding this to the 17.1 .threading version however I know very little about how this works and where I might find a solution, Hence, I am here :).  Although my post on the DeveloperCommunity is still active I'm hoping a resolution here maybe faster!

Thank you!

[image: Fusion Error]
[image: Visual Studio Error]

Comment: The Microsoft dev had the same thought, but checking both the devenv.exe.config file in the program files folder and the appdata local folder they are both pointing to 17.0 , But thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the above is incorrect, you can't even get to the startup screen.

The correct answer is you need to remove the V15 version of the dll from the GAC. Instructions from MS can be found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-create-the-window---VS-2022-172/10040806?space=8&q=2022%20cannot%20create%20the%20window).

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too, and its becouse you dont have defined startup project.

Right click on your startup project and choose "set as startup project".